# モデレーションによる削除済みページに英語が残っている

Tags: バグ, 完了, 翻訳

モデレーションにより自動削除された場合に表示される[404エラーページ](https://ja.stackoverflow.com/questions/56549/)に英語が残っています。
※信頼度が高いと削除済ページが見えてしまうので、その場合はログアウトまたはブラウザを変えてご確認をお願いします。

> Page not found
>   This question was removed from スタック・オーバーフロー for reasons of moderation. Please refer to the help center [for possible explanations why a question might be removed](https://ja.stackoverflow.com/help/deleted-questions).

なおURL間違いなどで元々存在しない場合の[404エラーページ](https://ja.stackoverflow.com/questions/page-not-found/)は日本語化されています。

> Page not found
>   指定されたページは存在しませんでした。

Answer (score 4, accepted):

https://ja.traducir.win/string/10549 で提案しておきましたので、反映されるまでしばらくお待ちください。

「[太字の装飾あり](https://ja.traducir.win/string/2756)」から「装飾なし」に原文の文字列が変更になった影響かと思います。

Comment: 日本語化されていることを確認しました。